# Displaying has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a quick question about displaying a has many through associations.

I have the below associations set up in 3 different models

```
assignment.rb 
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :stock
 belongs_to :portfolio
end

portfolio.rb
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :stocks, through: :assignments
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :stocks
end

stock.rb
class Stock < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :assignments
 has_many :portfolios, through: :assignments
end
```

and what i am trying to do is display all the stocks that a portfolio has on the portfolio index page after you assign a stock to a portfolio

I currently have this in my portfolio index view

```
<% @portfolios.stocks.each do |a|%>
  <p><%= a.ticker %></p>
<%end%>
```

but i am getting the below error

```
undefined method `stocks' for #<Portfolio::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x51f0fd8>
```

i don't understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: You're trying to get `stocks` on portfolios in the example you mentioned. 
You can get stocks of a `portfolio` by writing `@portfolios.first.stocks`. `.stocks` works on a `ActiveModel::Model` not `ActiveModel::Model`

Comment: can you show your controller method as well?

Comment: If you still need all the stocks for `@portfolios` then you can write `Stock.joins(:portfolios).where(portfolios: { id: @portfolios.pluck(:id) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ActiveRecord::Relation` is an array like object containing several records. In your case `Portfolio` instances.

To call instance methods on the records (like `#stocks`) you need to iterate through the collection:

```
<% @portfolios.each do |portfolio|%>
<div class="portfolio">
  <% portfolio.stocks.each do |stock| %>
    <p><%= stock.ticker %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

When doing this make sure to use `.includes` or `.eager_load` to [avoid a N+1 query](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations):

```
def index
  @portfolios = Portfolio.includes(:stocks).all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you've defined that you've a `many to many` relationship between `portfolios` and `stocks`.

which means for every **porfolio** you've multiple records of **stocks**.

So, to get all the stocks related to a portfolio you'll have to use `some_porfolio.stocks`

your code is not working because you're using an array of `active_record` and you are asking it to fetch stocks for all the portfolios in one go but relationship is not between array of `active_records` and array of `active_records`. Instead it's between a single `active_record` holding `foreign_key` of another active record.

If you want to show a list of stocks against the record of a portfolio then it's better to use

```
<% @portfolios.each do |porfolio| %>
  <!--- your html code for each portfolio -->
  ID: <%= portfolio.id %>
  <!--- your html code for each stock associated to this portfolio -->
  <% portfolio.stocks.each do |stock| %>
    <!--- your html code for each stock -->
    ID: <%= stock.id %>
  <% end %>  
<% end %>
```